# CSS: Unable to transition dropdrop menu

Tags: css

I am using the following code to create a responsive meny. But the problem is on clicking it not transitions as expected, it opens instantaneously

```js
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('.navicon-container').click(function () {
            $('header nav').toggle();
//            $('header nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
        })
    })
```

```css
 *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body{
            font-size: 62.5%;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        header{
            background-color: #222222;
        }

        .nav-container{
            margin: 0 100px;
        }

        .nav-container:after{
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        nav ul{
            font-size: 2em;
            list-style-type: none;
            transition: height 0.6s;
        }

        ul li{
            display: inline;
        }

        ul li a{
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            color: #bdbdbd;
        }

        ul li a:hover{
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.3);
        }

        header h1{
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 2em;
            padding: 10px 0px;
            color: #bdbdbd;
        }

        header nav{
            float: right;
        }

        .navicon-container{
            border: 1px solid rgba(247, 239, 241, 0.87);
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 7px 0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            /* display: none; */
            float: right;
            padding: 5px 6px;
            display: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .navicon{
            border-top: 10px double #ffffff;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
            height: 4px;
            width: 20px;
            /*margin: 10px 10px;*/
            padding: 0px 2px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 880px) {
            .nav-container {
                margin: 0 25px;
                font-size: 1em;
            }

            header nav ul{
                height: 0;
            }

            .showing{
                height: 160px;
            }

            .nav-container a{
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }

            .navicon-container{
                display: inline-block;
            }

            header nav{
                display: none;
                float: none;
                clear: both;
                text-align: center;
            }

            ul li {
                display: block;
            }

            ul li a{
                display: block;
                border-radius: 2.5px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <h1>ORG</h1>
        <div class="navicon-container">
            <div class="navicon">
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

.

What is the problem please help ?

Here is the link to the demo on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ppat/Ldvyfdes/

Thanks

Comment: What transition are you expecting? `toggle();` just sets an item to `display: none;` and then back to it's original display, which has no inherent transitions.

Comment: i want to slide down/up on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('.navicon-container').click(function () {
            //$('header nav').toggle(400);
            $('header nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
        })
    })
```

```css
 *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body{
            font-size: 62.5%;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        header{
            background-color: #222222;
        }

        .nav-container{
            margin: 0 100px;
        }

        .nav-container:after{
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        nav ul{
            font-size: 2em;
            list-style-type: none;
            transition: height 0.6s;
            background-color: cyan;
        }

        ul li{
            display: inline;
        }

        ul li a{
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            color: #bdbdbd;
        }

        ul li a:hover{
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.3);
        }

        header h1{
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 2em;
            padding: 10px 0px;
            color: #bdbdbd;
        }

        header nav{
            float: right;
        }

        .navicon-container{
            border: 1px solid rgba(247, 239, 241, 0.87);
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 7px 0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            /* display: none; */
            float: right;
            padding: 5px 6px;
            display: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .navicon{
            border-top: 10px double #ffffff;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
            height: 4px;
            width: 20px;
            /*margin: 10px 10px;*/
            padding: 0px 2px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 880px) {
            .nav-container {
                margin: 0 25px;
                font-size: 1em;
            }

            header nav ul{
                height: 0px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            .showing{
                height: 160px;
            }

            .nav-container a{
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }

            .navicon-container{
                display: inline-block;
            }

            header nav{
                float: none;
                clear: both;
                text-align: center;
            }

            ul li {
                display: block;
            }

            ul li a{
                display: block;
                border-radius: 2.5px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <h1>ORG</h1>
        <div class="navicon-container">
            <div class="navicon">
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```